# Error While Compiling Magento 2 admin page module

Tags: magento2, admin-controller, compilation

I'm getting error while compiling the Magento 2 admin module. The error which I'm getting is

> Fatal error: `Class Tutorial\SimpleNews\Controller\Adminhtml\News`
>   contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or
>   implement the remaining methods
>   `(Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface::execute)` in
>       /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MagentoTest/app/code/Tutorial/SimpleNews/Controller/Adminhtml/News.php
>   on line 60

**Here is my code:**

```
    <?php

namespace Tutorial\SimpleNews\Controller\Adminhtml;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Tutorial\SimpleNews\Model\NewsFactory;

class News extends Action
{
    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry;

    /**
     * Result page factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $_resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * News model factory
     *
     * @var \Tutorial\SimpleNews\Model\NewsFactory
     */
    protected $_newsFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Registry $coreRegistry
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     * @param NewsFactory $newsFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Registry $coreRegistry,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        NewsFactory $newsFactory
    ) {
       parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_newsFactory = $newsFactory;
    }

    /**
     * News access rights checking
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Tutorial_SimpleNews::manage_news');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.. you need to add the execute method in the controller action..eg:-

```
public function execute() {

    $this->resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    $this->resultPage->setActiveMenu('Tutorial_SimpleNews::manage');
    return $this->resultPage;       
}
```

Comment: Still I'm getting the same Error..

Comment: Actually the correct way of writing a controller action in M2 is we have to create a folder inside Adminhtml and then place the controller in that.Try to do in that way. It seems your controller action file is correct. Dont forget to clear generation.

Comment: Sorry I have wrongly updated the code..

Comment: I have updated the code. please have a look

Comment: You must add the execute method for the controller and then you can add your remaining methods too.

Comment: your fatal error msg and namespace are different please check...

Answer (score -2):

Default Abstract clss is required.

```
class News extends Action
```

change to

```
abstract class News extends Action
```

execute method not required.

So your file at `app\code\Tutorial\SimpleNews\Controller\Adminhtml\New.php`

```
<?php namespace Tutorial\SimpleNews\Controller\Adminhtml;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Tutorial\SimpleNews\Model\NewsFactory;

abstract class News extends Action
{


   /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry;

    /**
     * Result page factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $_resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * News model factory
     *
     * @var \Tutorial\SimpleNews\Model\NewsFactory
     */
    protected $_newsFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Registry $coreRegistry
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     * @param NewsFactory $newsFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Registry $coreRegistry,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        NewsFactory $newsFactory
    ) {
       parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_newsFactory = $newsFactory;
    }

    /**
     * News access rights checking
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Tutorial_SimpleNews::manage_news');
    }
}
?>
```